# how to set loadFromRemoteSources enabled=true for a specific folder

Tags: .net, assemblies

my application has two folders, one has the exe file developed by another team. We have the dlls in another folder.

When this application is calling in the server machine. fine. However, when running this appliction from a client via the network share. The Assembly.loadfile failed due to some dlls are not found.

At the app.exe.config, add loadFromRemoteSources enabled=true, the exe calling dlls from the client machine works. However, in our dlls, Assmebly.loadfile still not works. Can someone tell me what is the issue here? Why the calling dlls from the exe works via the Assembly.Loadfile works, however, in side our own coding, assembly.load file failed?